# Hosting Laravel on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting

I'm trying to install Laravel 5.5.14 on a shared host. (5.4 worked fine for my sub domain on same host)

So i installed Laravel with softaculous and whenever i go to my domain it throws a HTTP 500 Error.

I have no idea why it's doing it as Laravel 5.4 works on the same host but on a subdomain.

> AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pitpitpit/domains/pit-pit-pit.nl/public_html/.htaccess is the apache error log error.

**htaccess**

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}
</IfModule>
```

Comment: isn't laravel 5.5 PHP7+ only? The response headers on your server say it runs on 5.5.38...

Comment: @Pevara changed it to 7.1 still the same.. Also added the pastebin contents to the post itself.

Comment: Usually with Laravel, only the ``public`` directory is visible from the web server

Comment: That doesnt really help my issue though..

Comment: No one can help me? :(